# Where does the function auth.authenticate() check if user exists?

Tags: django, authentication

I have a login form. Also I have a huge database. One of the tables in DB is 'zusers', where stores information about users: `username`, `password`, 'telefon' and some other columns. I learned about `user = auth.authenticate(username = 'John', password = 'pass')`. And the question: wheredoes this function check if such user exists or no? And how to do it so that this function check for users in my DB table 'zusers'?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom authentication backend in Django for your exisiting users. You can read more at the Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

You should not need to manual check `auth.authenticate` but just swap out the backend.

You can also  substitute a completely customised model for your Django user to support `telefon` and the other columns you have https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/

I am not going to post any example code as you haven't provided any yourself and the Django links above very clearly show you how to achieve this.

Comment: I read an article about authentication backend, so I still have a question: how to create a User model for every row in my DB? There is an explanation in article, that we can create a new User model for every login attempt. But how to transfer all Users from my DB to extended User models?